# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/Polyfit (wrong name: jamlab/Polyfit)

Tags: java, jama

I am getting this error, with the compiler pointing to line 46:

[image: Error Screenshot]

I've gone through the Polyfit class, but do not know how to correct this.

[image]

Comment: The compiler isn't pointing anywhere. This is a runtime exception. Don't post pictures of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by incorrect packaging of your JAR file. The directory name a .class file is under must agree with its package name in the source file.

Comment: how can i get the file to agree with the package name in the source file?